# Button not disappearing with setVisibility(View.GONE)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility, android-button

I am displaying a go to top button on scroll up on a `RecyclerView`. If user scrolls up the button is displayed.

Here is the xml code which is nested in a `RelativeLayout`.

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/userFeedsRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_goto_top"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="@string/icon_up_arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
```

Here is the java code

```java
btnGotoTop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_goto_top);
    Const.setTypeFace(btnGotoTop, getApplication());
    btnGotoTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userFeedsRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });


    userFeedsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if(dy < 0){
                btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Inside the `onClick()` method of `btnGotoTop`, the `RecyclerView` scrolls to the top properly but the button does not disappear.
I tried changing `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to `btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE)` but the button is displayed even after scrolling is complete.

Comment: Remove visibility from XML and Try again

Comment: @AkshayRohilla tried it. didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. Changed visibility of button in onScrollStateChanged() of RecyclerView's  OnScrollListener

```
btnGotoTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            userFeedsRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            headerAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
        }
    });

private boolean isUserFeedRecyclerViewAtTop(){

    int numColumns = 2;
    int pos[] = new int[numColumns];
    ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager)(userFeedsRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(pos);
    return pos[0] == 0;
}

userFeedsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            switch (newState){
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if(isUserFeedRecyclerViewAtTop()) {
                        btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    break;
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                    break;
                case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if(dy < 0 && btnGotoTop.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (dy > 0 && btnGotoTop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong. You are making button visible on scrolling but you want to show only when its down.
change this

```
if(dy < 0){
            btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

to

```
if(dy > 0){
            btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**, I also recommend you to use floating action button here. I created a simple project in case you wanna have a look for recylerView with **FloatingActionButton** with same functionality required. [Link.](https://github.com/imprashant7k/recylerView)

```
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
           if (dy > 0 && btnGotoTop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
           {
                    btnGotoTop.hide();

           } else if (dy < 0 && btnGotoTop.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) 
           {
                    btnGotoTop.show();
           }

    }
});
```

Comment: the logic of showing and hiding the button on scroll works fine. 

What doesn't work is hiding the button when the scrolltoposition is complete. I was pointing at the onClick() method for the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean IsRecyclerViewAtTop(){
    if (userFeedsRecyclerView.getChildCount() == 0)
        return true;
    return userFeedsRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}


userFeedsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (IsRecyclerViewAtTop())
                {
                    btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy < 0 && btnGotoTop.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                    btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (dy > 0 && btnGotoTop.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){

                    btnGotoTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Use `IsRecyclerViewAtTop` method to find out if recycler view scrolled to top and call it is `onScrollStateChanged` method.

Comment: Hi. I tried this code. It didn't work. The button is still visible once the scroll to top is complete.

Comment: You might be missing something, do you changed onScrolled method code?

Comment: Yea. I added the exact same code snippet that you posted  including the onScrolled method.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mrVXvmi-pdp9UYo8-koaKYczCuepNPtB/view?usp=sharing
Check this link, i have uploaded code

Comment: Thanks for uploading code. I went through it and adapted my code to match it. Problem is it still does not work.

I think the smoothScrollToPosition() makes dy < 0 and triggers onScrolled method which  makes the button visible again.